# Estou fazendo um programa simples para estudar Vetores, quando vou rodar aparece o erro "Index was outside the bounds of the array" na linha 24

Tags: c#, array

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {

         int i, n;

        Console.WriteLine("Entre com o número de Alunos: ");
        n = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        String[] nome = new String [n];
        Double[] n1 = new Double[n];
        Double[] n2 = new Double[n];
        Double[] m = new Double[n];


        for (i=1; i<=n; i++);
        {
         Console.WriteLine("Entre com o seu nome: ");
         nome[i] = Console.ReadLine();
         Console.WriteLine("Entre com o a sua primeira nota: ");
         n1[i] = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
         Console.WriteLine("Entre com o a sua segunda nota: ");
         n2[i] = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());

          m[i] = (n1[i] + n2[i])/2;

         Console.WriteLine("Seu nome é: {0} " , nome);
         Console.WriteLine("Sua média é: {0} " , m);

        }
    }
}
```

Erro

> Index was outside the bounds of the array

na linha 24.

Comment: `for` tem de ir de `0 a n-1`. Os arrays começam sempre em `0`

Answer (score 1):

mude seu for

> `for (i=1; i<=n; i++);`

para

```
for (i=0; i<n; i++);
```

Os índices do `array` começam em 0, então em um `array` de tamanho 5, 
os índices serão:

```
[0], [1], [2], [3], [4]
```

Ou seja, inicia em 0, e termina no tamanho -1

O seu `for` atual, tentaria acessar:

```
[1], [2], [3], [4], [5]
```

como não existe posição 5, é retornado o erro:

> "O índice estava fora dos limites da matriz"